# RDWeb server 2012 r2 giving me a second login

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have server 2012 r2 setup as a virtual host.  I have setup 2 virtual servers using hyper-v...

The 2 setup are a domain controller and an RDP server both 2012 r2.  I have then setup RDWeb.  I can login to see the links for the resources, clicking on the links downloads the remote app and then it asks for credentials again....  I know it is an easy answer, what is it that I am missing?

Here are pictures of what it looks like. In the secondary login picture the top image was under the bottom one

[resource picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uap5.png)

[Secondary login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZpBN.png)

Comment: This question is not about programming and thus is off-topic on Stack Overflow. It would be better to ask such question on [sf], but please read their help center before posting there.

Comment: I have had lots of help here before with server topics, from other people

Comment: Yes, there are many users eager to answer any question they can (some to gain more reputation, some simply to help), but that doesn't make this question [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions on _professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.

Comment: Thanks for the redirect to the other forum